# Making ListView in SLideMenu like YouTube App

Tags: android, listview

I want to emulate this type of Listview in a SlideMenu.  I have the SlideMenu working fine.  It is a ListFragment.  I want to copy this pattern like the YouTube app on Android:

[image]

I essentially have a couple of list items I need to add to the top of the list of categories.  And I want a Header to separate.

I want this:

```
Home
Profile
Top Items

Header that says Categories
And List of Categories
```

I already have the Categories listed out fine on my `SlideMenu`.  They come from an `adapter` that populate from a table in `MySQL`.  But the three top items do not come from that same table (or ANY table).  Is the top portion a header to a `ListView`?  Is it its OWN `ListView`? or..?

Keep in mind, I want ability to sort the list (which I already have via a `spinner`).  So Categories must be dynamic.  But *how to I add a couple of static items above* AND *make a header*?

I don't really need code sample, I just want to know method to implement this.

**EDIT:  Here is Code in progress**
This show the separator like the Channels line in the Youtube example.  Need to also figure out how to add those two or three static lines up top.

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        View rowView = convertView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        int type = getItemViewType(position);

        if (rowView == null) {

            switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mastercat_layout, null,
                        true);
                holder.textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
                holder.textView.setTypeface(tf);
                holder.imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mastercat_layout_separate, null);

                break;
            }

            rowView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        holder.textView.setText(getItem(position));
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        return rowView;

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need a couple pools of convertView in adapter?
BaseAdapter contains methods

```
public int getItemViewType (int position)
```

and

```
public int getViewTypeCount ()
```

You can override it to implement 2 pools of views - one for Headers and another one for Items of listView. Also in this case you need to change you getView method according to itemViewType, returned by getItemViewType().

Comment: So in `getItemViewType()`, do I do something like, `if (position == 0)   { do this }`? etc? Would I have to define ALL ListView rows or just the special instances?

Comment: Wait, so getItemViewType assigns the type of view to the different rows, but the types of view are still created ... in getView?

Comment: in `getItemViewType()` you should return int number - this is type of view, that should be displayed on this position. This method should contains logic of determining type of view (is this header of sublist or just a list item).

And yes, type of view created in getView method.

Comment: `public View getView(View view, int position, ...) {
   if (view == null) {
       if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
           view = new HeaderView(mContext);
       } else {  
           view = new ListItem(mContext);
       }
    }
}`

You need something like this.
Sorry for formatting =(

Comment: Found a great example at:  http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296  Marking you correct because this clearly is what I need!  I get the getView part, just need to figure out those two methods (adding code I have so far as an fyi).  Thanks!