# Slidingmenu jfeinstein10 group

Tags: android, menu

I try to custom Slidingmenu but not success. I want sliding menu like Youtute, it 's has groups: Account, Channel, From Youtube. I use Slidingmenu jfeinstein10.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118643/making-listview-in-slidemenu-like-youtube-app

Comment: Final i use this: http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Comment: Not even a vote up? :(

Comment: May be only someone use this. :)